# SQL Query based on HTML selection input

Tags: html, sql, flask

I am developing a webapp in Flask. My data is stored in BigQuery. I want to write sql query based on what the user selects from the html input interface. 
[Click here to see my Data Table in BigQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny9fe.png)

Currently I was hardcoding the input that I wanted to query, "Glycol_Supply" in this case, but I want the user to select from the HTML input and show results based on that.

```
def queryBuilder():
query = """SELECT Record_Start_Time, Glycol_Supply 
         FROM Furnace_Output.DataTable
         WHERE Record_Start_Time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("{}") 
         AND TIMESTAMP("{}")
         ORDER BY Record_Start_Time
         LIMIT 100""".format(request.form['start'],request.form['end'])  
return query
```

The user will be selecting from the HTML input interface:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('query') }}" method="post">
            <p>Query Database</p>
            <select name ="Data Points " id="Data Points" widht="300px" required/>
            <option value="Record_Start_Time ">Record Start Time</option>
            <option value="Glycol_Supply ">Glycol Supply</option>
            <option value=" Glycol_Return ">Glycol Return</option>
            </select>

            <p>Start Time <input type = "text" name = "start" /></p>
            <p>End Time <input type = "text" name = "end" /></p>
            <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def queryBuilder():
    query = """SELECT Record_Start_Time, {}
    FROM Furnace_Output.DataTable
    WHERE Record_Start_Time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("{}") 
    AND TIMESTAMP("{}")
    ORDER BY Record_Start_Time
    LIMIT 100""".format(request.form['Data Points'] , 
  request.form['start'],request.form['end'])  
return query
```